# SQL Server Check Constraint with UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I'm trying to generate a safe way to make sure a years range record added in a table doesn't overlap with an existing record.

I created my table, created an udf and created the check constraints, and bizarrely enough they don't work when they should

Query used to create table, udf and constraints:

```
Create Table EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings
(
    ProductCode int not null,
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    MinYear int not null, 
    MaxYear int not null
)

alter table EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings
    add constraint PK_VehicleProductCatSetting 
    Primary Key nonclustered (ProductCode, Name, MinYear, MaxYear)
go

Create Function CheckIfYearRangeExists
     (@Year int, @ProductCode int)
returns smallint
as 
begin
    declare @ret varchar(5);

    declare @count smallint;
    set @count = 0;

    select @count = count(productcode) 
    from EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings 
    where @Year between MinYear and MaxYear
      and ProductCode = @ProductCode

    return @count
end 
go

alter table EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings
    add constraint CK_MinYear
        check (dbo.CheckIfYearRangeExists(minyear, productcode) = 0)

alter table EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings
    add constraint CK_MaxYear
        check (dbo.CheckIfYearRangeExists(maxyear, productcode) = 0)
go
```

Insert used to test:

```
INSERT INTO EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings(ProductCode, Name, MinYear, MaxYear)
VALUES (400, 'a',2015, 2019)
```

This doesn't work. It rolls back the insert and says I'm violating my constraint.

What am I missing?

Comment: if you run the insert twice this your insert will fail

Comment: I'm just running it once. I'm using the exact code posted.

Comment: i ran your create, alter constraint and insert all works fine here but if i run the insert again this will fail.

Comment: Yeah if you insert it again it should fail. And yet I can't get it to work once on SQL Server 2012

Comment: Do you already have a 400,'a' in the table?  If so, does it have a maxyear of 2015?

Comment: note that BETWEEN is inclusive, so if a product has a maxyear of 2015, you cannot enter a minyear of 2015 for that product, based on your query.

Comment: No, the table is empty. That's the main thing, the table is completely empty.

Comment: That query should work as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

RUN these and tell me if you can

```
Create Table EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings
(
ProductCode int not null,
Name varchar(100) not null,
MinYear int not null, 
MaxYear int not null
)
go

alter table EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings
add constraint PK_VehicleProductCatSetting Primary Key nonclustered (ProductCode)
go


/* run once */

INSERT  INTO EasyBankVehicleProductsCatSettings(ProductCode, Name, MinYear, MaxYear)
VALUES (400, 'a',2015, 2019)
```

Comment: 1 rows affected. That one runs fine but doesn't have the constraint

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm interested on the constraint running. If it works with you on the first insert it should work with me. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: the constraint will only hit if you insert more than once of the same data. so basically when you see the violation that's the constraint

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is it is not letting me insert the first record. It's not letting me run the insert once. That's the problem.

Comment: can you post the contents of your table?

Comment: Once I try to run the insert once it's giving me an error saying I'm violating the constraint When I'm not really.

Comment: It's empty. It doesn't have any records.

Comment: what is returned when you run the udf with those values?

Comment: @WesH he's testing the insert at this stage and not the UDF

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, I understand that, but I'd like to confirm the UDF is return what he is expecting for the values he is testing.

Comment: The Udf is returning what it should return. But the insert is failing even when the table is empty which is bizarre.

Comment: @WesH You're right, but sadly that's not the issue I'm tackling.